# Css Rescaling Fixed Banner

Tags: javascript, html, css, web, meteor

So quick question, I haven't been able to find the correct phrasing perhaps in google but I'm attempting to make a `fixed` banner will scale when the page is resized.  I've found that using a percentage width works for at least the large container, however my banner container within the main container will not rescale into that adequately (The banner is extending longer than the main container).

CSS:

```
.contMain {
        width:80%;
        position: top
        padding-top: 0;
        border-top: 0;
        margin: 0 auto;
        background-color: #F1EDCC;
     }
.contMain-banner {
         position:fixed;
         width: inherit;
         background: #87AADF;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div class="contMain">
    <div class="contMain-banner">
        <h1 class="contMain-title">Some Title</h1>
          {{> MeteorTemplate}}
    </div>
</div>
```

The only higher level css is a `.body` tag in css for a background color.  I am using *MeteorJS* for this. Cheers

Comment: Here's a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/c4e0syq5/. The .contMain-banner seems to get wider and narrower as I resize. Could you describe what specifically you observe and how that differs from what you're expecting?

Comment: Of course.  Sorry so the problem is that unless I define .contMain as a static px count, when the .contMain-banner sets width as width:inherit; it is just slightly longer than the main container.  Additionally if I try to do 100% it runs off the screen to the right while the left side lines up exactly

Comment: I suppose my current goal is to line the banner exactly up with the main container without needing to statically determine the size of the main container

Answer (score 0):

Try this - codepen [here](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/xbgdmG)

css

```
body {
height:100%;
width:100%;
}
.contMain {
    height:150px;
    width:80%;
    padding:0;
    margin: 0 auto;
    background-color: #333333;
 }
.contMain-banner {
     position:fixed;
     width: inherit;
     height:auto;
     background: #d7d7d7;
}
span {
color:#fff;
position:absolute;
top:125px;
}
```

HTML

```
<body>
 <div class="contMain">
  <div class="contMain-banner">
      <h1 class="contMain-title">Main Content Banner</h1>
        {{> MeteorTemplate}}
  </div>
    <span>This is the main container</span>
 </div>
</body>
```